# Publish Phonegap Build App at Apple's App Store - Experiences?

Tags: ios, cordova, deployment, publish

we want to build our HTML5 App through Phonegap Build for the App Store.
Has anyone else published a Phonegap App to the App Store? Or is there any difference in publishing to the App Store to a normal "native" App?

Of course any information about that would be very helpful!

Thanks for your help!

Greets
Felix

Answer (score 3):

**The review process is same as for other iOS apps**. **The Apple guidelines are available [here](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html)**. Apps are evaluate based on a range of criteria, including user interface design, functionality, content, and the use of specific technologies.

PhoneGap obviously gives you access to all the device features, so you have all you need to build an app that complies with the guidelines. Here is some authentic tips (one from Phonegap) that you must take care-
[one here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/phonegap/articles/apple-application-rejections-and-phonegap-advice.html) & 
[another](https://build.phonegap.com/blog/new-apple-app-store-submittal-rules)

Answer (score 1):

I published a Phonegap App to the AppStore and there are absolutely no differences!