# How to build signed Phonegap2.9 project for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

This is a project which use **phonegap 2.9** for iPhone app. Now I use **phonegap's build tool** to build an .app file, But this .app file is not signed. What I want to know is:

**Can I use phonegap's build tool to build a signed .app file?**

More about my project:

1. I have to use command line to build my project.
2. I have tried to use `xcodebuild` with param `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY` to build it, but is failed with `<Cordova/CDVViewController.h> file not found` message.

I need you help. Thansk a lot!

Comment: I have to use command line to build my project.
or use xcodebuild.

Answer (score 0):

To publish the in apple store at first you need to build an ipa file.
To build ipa file you need to archive the project.
Archive can be found here:
Project>Archive. (Be sure to choose iOS device in Run option).

To carry out all these task you will need provision file from your developer account.

For more detail you can go through these links:

1. [How to get ipa file from Xcode to run an iPhone app in real device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595925/how-to-get-ipa-file-from-xcode-to-run-an-iphone-app-in-real-device)
2. [Deploy .ipa file in App store generated by Phonegap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738559/deploy-ipa-file-in-app-store-generated-by-phonegap)
3. [Publish Phonegap Build App at Apple's App Store - Experiences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395338/publish-phonegap-build-app-at-apples-app-store-experiences)